# Loop dates and list vertically

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to list dates of the month vertically, so far my table looks as followed:

[image]

I have today's date however I need to list 18 days from today vertically. As well as generate the cells against these dates. From my index.html.erb I understand that  I have the following `@dates` variable isn't being set properly in my controller.

> `@dates` variable isn't being set properly, if you add the statement
>   <%= debug @dates %> to your view you can inspect what it's being

Controller: [Gist - Controller.rb](https://gist.github.com/3998126)

Index: [Gist - Index.html.erb](https://gist.github.com/3998129)

Model: [Gist - Model.rb](https://gist.github.com/3998134)

I understand that I will need to change my controller's index action so it is able to list 18 days from today. I was thinking of doing something somewhat similar.. - `Time.now+18.days` However I am not sure if something like this would solve my problems? As I'm not fully sure how to implement this into my controller. What is the best possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t1 = Date.today
t2 = Date.today.end_of_month
@dates = (t1..t2).to_a 
# (t1..t2) is a Range object - .to_a call will change it to an array object with values in the range as elements
```